# MYSQL: How to join two tables using Inner join and then calculatin the total number from the second table for the following examples

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck with the following requirement and I am finding it difficult to crack the query for it.

Consider a table **customer** with the following fields

```
id   signup_date  first_payment_date 
10    2015-03-20     null
11    2015-03-20     null
12    2015-03-20     null
13    2015-03-20     null
14    2015-05-23     null
15    2015-05-23     null
```

Consider another table **transaction_history**

```
id   product_name
10    vod trial
10    vod trial 
11    vod trial
12    vod trial
12    vod
13    vod trial
14    vod trial
15    vod trial
15    vod trial
```

I need to pick the `id`from **customer** table and look up in **transaction_history** table based on the `signup_date` and `first_payment_date` is `null`.

Now I need to check if this `id` is present in **transaction_history** and check if he has at least 1 entry with `product_name = "vod trial"`. If he has then he is a row in the result I want.

At the end I need to calculate the total number of id's from **transaction_history** who has at least one row where `product_name="vod_trial"` and this should be on a date basis mentioned in `signup_date` in **customer** table.

I wrote a query in the following manner:

```
SELECT 
    ts.guid,
    cs.signup_date,
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(ts2.guid)
     FROM
        transaction_history ts2
     WHERE
        cs.guid = ts2.guid
        AND ts2.product_name = "vod trial"
    HAVING COUNT(ts2.guid) = 1) AS count_ts_guid
FROM
    customer AS cs,
    transaction_history AS ts
WHERE
    cs.guid = ts.guid
    AND cs.first_payment_date IS NULL;
```

But in the above query I am not able to calculate the total count *signup_datewise*.

Would be great if someone could help me out.

Sample result:

```
date         new trials
2015-03-20      2
2015-05-23      1
```

Comment: Post expected results to help clairify. Seems to me a having product_name='vod_trial' and just acount

Comment: Expected result is:
signup_date           total 

2015-03-20             1
2015-05-13             0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd better make this a separate answer. You want to find customers that have only one entry in transaction_history and that entry must be 'vod trial'. So read the transaction table, group by customer id and count. Check your criteria with HAVING. Then join the found IDs with the customer table and group by date.

```
select c.signup_date, count(*)
from customer c
join
(
  select id
  from transaction_history
  group by id
  having count(*) = 1
  and min(product_name) = 'vod trial'
) t on t.id = c.id
group by c.signup_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand. You want customers without first_payment_date that have a trial entry in the transaction table?

```
select *
from customer
where first_payment_date is null
and id in (select id from transaction_history where product_name = 'vod trial');
```

Okay, from your last comment it seems, you want customers that have no trial entry in the transaction table, too. And you want to display them with their trial transaction count. So:

```
select signup_date, 
  (
    select count(*) 
    from transaction_history th
    where th.product_name = 'vod trial'
    and th.id = c.id
  )
from customer c
where first_payment_date is null;
```

If you even want to group by date, then aggregate:

```
select signup_date, 
  sum((
    select count(*) 
    from transaction_history th
    where th.product_name = 'vod trial'
    and th.id = c.id
  ))
from customer c
where first_payment_date is null
group by signup_date;
```

Next try: Join all customers and transactions, such as to only get customers present in the transactions table. Then aggregate.

```
select c.signup_date, count(*) 
from customer c
join transaction_history th on th.id = c.id and th.product_name = 'vod trial'
where c.first_payment_date is null
group by c.signup_date;
```

Or do you want this:

```
select c.signup_date, count(case when th.product_name = 'vod trial' then 1 end) 
from customer c
join transaction_history th on th.id = c.id
where c.first_payment_date is null
group by c.signup_date;
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. I tried running the last query you sent which somewhat gives me what I want but there is one error I see, it gives me all the rows from customers table based on their id even if customer.id is not present in transaction_history.id. and this mainly happens when I do the group by on signup_date. But I need to do the group by to show them a datewise history

Comment: Well, sorry, it seems I still don't understand. I guessed three times, and obviously I guessed three times wrong. Please edit your question in order to clarify things. First of all your query and described tables don't match. You describe `customer` and `transaction_history`, but use `customers`, `tract_services` and `products`. Then please show more sample data and the desired results.

Comment: Hi I've edited the question now. And your third guess is absolutely what I require. 
Your query :

select signup_date, 
  sum((
    select count(*) .....
group by signup_date;

When I perform the query without group by it gives me columns from customer and transaction_history that are only present in both which is my desired result. But if I use group by then it gives me rows from customer that are present and not present in transaction_history.
I cannot ignore group by as I need the result to be datewise. hope this answers your comment.

Comment: That is not possible. Query 3 gives you the same data as query 2, only aggregated by date. As you only want matches in transaction table, the query is even simpler: join and count. As to your edit: Your sample data is as small as before and no desired results are shown. For example all customers (10 and 11) are present in transaction_history. But you say it's possible that customers are missing from that table, so why don't you show this in your sample? And why is there no sample result still? This isn't so hard to do. Anyway, I've added another query to my answer.

Comment: Edited with sample result

Comment: Now that's better :-) Unfortunately though, I don't understand the results. There are 4 customers for 2015-03-20. All have a vod trial entry, but your result shows a count of 2 for that date. How do you get that 2?

Comment: Exactly, that's what. I need to count only those customers that have a single entry as a vod trial. I need to only count them. If a customer has more than one vod trial entry in transaction_history then I do not have to count him.